# Multithreaded network application issues

Tags: c#, multithreading, networking, server

I've looked at least a hundred threads and none gave me a solution to my specific problem so far and i got tired of looking,

I'm trying to emulate a runescape game server in C#,

I need to receive lots of connections and parse the requests and send out responses for them until the game has loaded all the files, and then proceed to the actual login protocol. this needs to be able to handle multiple connections per second, as in, i handle 3 basic protocols "jaggrab", "ondemand" and then regular game protocol i.e; login, player updating etc these are all handled on the same port

My Server class listens for connections on one thread, while on another thread my PipelineFactory handles the connections in a Queue one by one as fast as it can, meanwhile there is a TaskPool thread which is executing PoolableTask objects at their own individual intervals... this works fine except as soon as I accept a connection both the pool and server threads begin to block and furthermore, the server object stops listening for connections all together but the thread seems to keep running.. I assume this is because the TcpListener.Pending() is not being updated? but i cant seem to find a function to update this list in the docs or anywhere

I seem to be using the threads the way all the multithreading tutorials explain them to work? i dont really understand what im doing wrong.. heres the important parts of my code:

MainEntry.cs:

```
using System; 
using System.Threading;   

using gameserver.evt;
using gameserver.io;
using gameserver;
using gameserver.io.player;

public static class MainEntry
{  

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Starting game server..."); 
        new Thread(new ThreadStart(Server.Run)).Start(); 
        new Thread(new ThreadStart(TaskPool.Run)).Start();
        new Thread(new ThreadStart(PipelineFactory.Run)).Start(); 
        //TODO maybe pool these
    }  

}
```

Server.cs:

```
using gameserver.io.player;
using gameserver.io.sql;
using gameserver.model;
using gameserver.model.player;
using util;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using gameserver.io.player.pipeline;
using gameserver.evt;
using util.cache;

namespace gameserver.io
{
    public class Server 
    {

        public static TcpListener serverSocket;
        public  static Dictionary<int, Player> players = new Dictionary<int, Player>(Constants.MaxPlayers); 
        public static Database database; 
        public const int ListenPort = 43594;
        public static bool running = true;
        public static readonly Cache cache = new Cache(Constants.CacheDir); 

        public static void Bind()
        {
            serverSocket = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0"), ListenPort);

            serverSocket.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Server started at 0.0.0.0:" + ListenPort); 
        }

        public static void Run()
        {
            if (serverSocket == null)
                Bind();
            while(IsRunning())
            {
            Console.Write("serve"); 
                    var incoming = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
                    if (incoming != null)
                    {
                        PipelineFactory.queue.Enqueue(new PlayerSocket(incoming));
                    }   
                Thread.Sleep(25);
            }  
        }

        private static void Destroy()
        {
            serverSocket.Stop();
            //saveall players 
            //Environment.Exit(0);
        }

        public static bool Online(Player player)
        {
            if(player == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < players.Count; i++)
            {
                if (player.username == players[i].username)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        public static Database Database => database ?? (database = new Database());
        public static bool IsRunning() => running;
    }
}
```

TickPool.cs:

```
using gameserver.io;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace gameserver.evt
{
    public class TaskPool 
    {

        public static bool running = true;
        public static List<PoolableTask> tasks = new List<PoolableTask>(); 

        public static void Run()
        { 
            do
             {
                long cur = Environment.TickCount;

                Console.Write("tick");
                foreach (PoolableTask t in tasks)
                {
                    if (cur - t.last >= t.interval)
                    {
                        if (t == null) 
                            continue; 
                        t.Execute();
                            t.last = cur; 
                    }

                }
                Thread.Sleep(100); 
            } while (Server.IsRunning());
        }

        public static void Add(PoolableTask task)
        {
            if(!tasks.Contains(task))
                tasks.Add(task); 
        } 

        public static void Stop(PoolableTask task)
        {
            if(tasks.Contains(task)) 
                tasks.Remove(task); 
        }

    }
}
```

PipelineFactory.cs:

```
using gameserver.evt;
using gameserver.io.player.pipeline;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace gameserver.io.player
{
    // simple but effective state machine for all non player model related protocol
    public class PipelineFactory
    {

        public static Queue<PlayerSocket> queue = new Queue<PlayerSocket>(100);
        private static readonly LoginPipe loginPipe = new LoginPipe();
        private static readonly JaggrabPipe jgpipe = new JaggrabPipe();
        private static readonly HandshakePipe handshake = new HandshakePipe();
        private static readonly OnDemandPipe ondemand = new OnDemandPipe();

        public static void Run()
        {
            while (Server.IsRunning())
            {
                Console.Write("pipe");

                if (queue.Count() > 0)
                {
                    var socket = queue.First();
                    if (socket == null || !socket.GetSocket().Connected
                        || socket.state == PipeState.Play)
                    {
                        queue.Dequeue();
                        return;
                    }

                    switch (socket.state)
                    {
                        case PipeState.Handshake:
                            socket.currentPipeline = handshake;
                            break;
                        case PipeState.Jaggrab:
                            socket.currentPipeline = jgpipe;
                            break;
                        case PipeState.OnDemand:
                            socket.currentPipeline = ondemand;
                            break;
                        case PipeState.LoginResponse:
                        case PipeState.Block:
                        case PipeState.Finalize:
                            socket.currentPipeline = loginPipe;
                            break;

                        case PipeState.Disconnect:
                            //TODO: Database.saveForPlayer
                            socket.Close();
                            break;
                    }
                    try
                    {
                        if (socket.currentPipeline != null)
                            socket.state = socket.currentPipeline.HandleSocket(socket);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        socket.Close();
                        queue.Dequeue();
                    }

                }
                Thread.Sleep(20);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The protocol itself really shouldn't matter just know it's all being handled asynchronously 
I'm a java programmer at heart but trying to delve into C# head first so thats why my conventions might not be perfect, and I don't really know how to/dont understand intellisense documentation but at some point ill look into it

EDIT: I just wanna note that everything worked perfectly before i tried using threads to multithread this, when i had the PipelineFactory a PoolableTask object implementation, it could handle multiple connections etc and there was only the main thread calling 2 while loops handling everything in the whole server, i'm trying to spread out the load over the cpu but its not working out for me lol

Comment: what exactly do you mean? this is half the reason im posting I dont really understand why this is "unsafe" to be blunt 

why cant these 3 threads coincide and execute one right after the other like clockwork? i dont understand..

Comment: It's very hard to on-screen debug something like this using posted excerpts. My immediate suggestion: get rid of all Sleep() calls. Instead use something like manual reset events that you can wait on in e.g. `PipelineFactory.Run()` and then set in the listener when a new connection is established. --- As for debugging the hang, logging is your friend. Good luck!

Comment: I added the calls to Thread.Sleep() to let the cpu rest in between thread executions, as the cpu usage would spike to 100% while the server was running. What exactly could you replace that with to keep the desired effect Thank you for the speedy response and sorry im retarded

Comment: By the way, is being multi threaded even that big a deal? would i be better off to make 3 seperate servers for each protocol and connect to them on 3 seperate ports? that would probably make the whole thing more scalable anyway to be honest and the protocols never communicate betweenst eachother or share a data structure other than a PlayerSocket object but those can easily be recycled with minimal memory usage

Comment: Take a look at the docs for [ManualResetEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.manualresetevent?view=netframework-4.7.2). It's actually quite simple to use, though explaining it is a bit long for a comment here. Using one of these will prevent the need for idle spinning (= pointless 100 percent CPU utilization).

Comment: I'm not sure how you detected that your threads block but I can see 2 problems in the code: 1) in the `PipelineFactory.Run` you always handle first item in the queue by `First()` method which doesn't modify the queue so you always deal with very first connection (until the moment when session is disconnected) regardless of how many items are in the queue, so other connections merely aren't served, and 2) you don't protect shared state from race conditions (in particular queue) which may lead to inconsistent behavior.

Comment: You know i am getting some very inconsistent behavior only when trying to multi-thread.. I'm really gonna have to read into thread safety, race conditions and stuff like that because I really don't understand what it all means, but thank you for your responses both very helpful
As for the queue not handling the rest of the items, how could i get around that just ensure that I handle every single item in the queue every time? maybe a for loop
I have read up on the thread stuff a bit but its confusing as fk to be honest